# List all the words that can be made from user input characters (Java array)

Tags: java, arrays, indexof

```java
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TYM6 {
    String[] words = {"and", "love", "vole", "levo", "the"};

    public  void start() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Do not remove for automated testing to work

        System.out.print("Enter your characters: ");
        String chars = sc.nextLine();

       try
       {
            for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
            {
                boolean display = true;
                if (words[i].length() == chars.length()) {
                    for (int c = 0; c < chars.length(); c++) {
                        if (Arrays.asList(words).indexOf(chars.charAt(c)) == -1) {
                            display = false;
                            System.out.println("No match");
                        }
                    }
                    if (display) {
                        for (String word : words) {
                            System.out.println(word);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       }catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Couldn't find the list of words!");
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TYM6 tym6 = new TYM6();
        tym6.start();
    }
}
```

I have array of words. The program have to match user typed words with words in array. Each letter can 
be used only once in any order. The text input  by the user must not be one of the word generated. After user input of strings characters program should lists all of the English words that can be made from those characters. But I can not see my mistake.

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Why are you making a list of the `words` array, `Arrays.asList(words)`, inside a loop where you are iterating the `words` array? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Does it make sense to print out _**all** the words_ in the list every time you find one word that matches the user's input?  You should be putting each matching work into a result list that will be printed out at the end.

Comment: Yes, I debug my code and I now understand that I make mistake becouse I put list in the loop. I'm thankful to you all. But as a person that just start to learn Java please can you write how I should solve problem? I don't understand how to make a result list?